# GoogleFinance: Get History By Month

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-query-language, text-formatting, google-finance

I use GoogleFinance quite a bit, but from the documentation it seems the only formats to get historical data is by Day or Week.

Is there any way to get the data by Month?

I guess I could add an extra column, and find the end of each month date to get the value using some calcs, but maybe there's a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TEXT(
 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), DATE(2021,2,1), "daily"), 
 {"yyyy mm", "@"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Now as a novice I need to do some study on the functions you used.  :)

Answer (score 1):

#### You can set the start and end date, use `QUERY` to remove headers, then take the `AVERAGE`

```
=AVERAGE(
  QUERY(
    GOOGLEFINANCE(
      "NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), DATE(2020,2,1), "DAILY"
    ), 
    "SELECT Col2 OFFSET 1"
  )
)
```

From inner to outer:

- `GOOGLEFINANCE` returns a list of the prices each day from Jan 1 2020 to Feb 1 2020.
- `QUERY` selects `Col2` with the prices and offsets the data from `GOOGLEFINANCE` so that the headers are no longer included. Now you have a simple list of numbers
- Finally `AVERAGE` just calculates the average.

#### Reference

- [`GOOGLEFINANCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`AVERAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615)

Comment: The use of QUERY to get rid of the Headers was helpful, although the solution from @player0 was the answer I needed. Cheers.