# Finding the average of monthly closing price on Google Finance

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, finance, google-finance

With Google Finance, I'm trying to calculate the 12-month moving average of a ticker. For example, I want to retrieve end-of-month closing price for a ticker for the last 12 months and find the average of these values.

I've tried to refer to this question: [GoogleFinance: Get History By Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295501/googlefinance-get-history-by-month)

Though I was able to retrieve the end-of-month closing prices, it wasn't letting me calculate the average of these values. I think this is because all the numbers are formatted as texts.

Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

EDIT: here is what I have so far and hopefully this provides a better sense of my desired outcome.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mf9wVli7ofJBGTaNTVrfGREMAwDNQwwO6nZWDwyGCbM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share with us what you have done so far and provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (sample spreadsheet with the sample data and formula used and maybe the desired output)?

Comment: Yes, please check out the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convert the text to number using `value()` function.

You may use the formula below:

`=average(arrayformula(value(B2:B14)))`

Output:

[image]

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have further questions related to this answer.