# Sorting in Google sheet

Tags: arrays, sorting

This is a follow up question to the answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68300634/9033073
How do I sort this table from oldest date to Recent.
Tried putting -1 but didn't show any output.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(data,QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "close", B1,D1,1),
"Select * Order By Col1 Asc Offset 1",0),
SORTN(data,9^9,2,EOMONTH(CHOOSECOLS(data,1),-1)+1,1))
```

This worked for me. Start Date is in B1 and End Date is in D1. Stock name is in B2